# Check Template Match is True OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

How can I check if the template is found and return it as true or false? Its by frames, I want the value to turn false when the object goes missing, else you know. This is what my script looks like:

```
zmatch = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_frame, template2, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
loc = np.where(zmatch >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(gray_frame, pt, (pt[0]+w, pt[1]+ h), (0, 225, 0), 2)
```

I tried all the few solution you can find by googling, no help.
- Checked if pt is valid(Its always valid)
- Checked if zmatch.any() is bigger or smaller than threshold

I don't know how to process it, please help! :3

Comment: `return len(loc) >0` ?

Comment: @Silencer Forgot to mention, I tried that but it always returns positive. Lets the the object is found once, it captures the locations but doesn't set to 0 once the object goes missing again. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: maybe your threshold is too small? it should return things that look quite similar to the template... it may not be there, but maybe something passed as good enough... try to make it higher to get a better criteria of acceptance

Comment: @api55 I am using .8 for threshold. Don't you think that's pretty high? I am really confused right now. :/

Comment: I tried printing lec(loc) > 0 and its always printing 2 no matter what.

Comment: Result of not found loc = (array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32))
Found loc = (array([123, 123, 123, 124], dtype=int32), array([149, 150, 151, 150], dtype=int32))

Comment: can you post a sample image and template?

Comment: @api55 thanks but i managed to make it work. Using np.array(loc).shape[1] > 0 gave me the result I wanted. np.array(loc).shape[1] > 0 will return true if template matches. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old, but for the people who googles this, this is the solution I used for the problem(the solution is at the bottom if you don't want to see my bs explaination):

Here is the code from the [opencv website](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) for matchTemplate:

```
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    print(pt) #this line I added myself to see the print result of pt
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
```

now this finds the locations of the matches, the length of locations I find is always positive and doesn't really change according to the number of matches(at least when I've tested it, limitedly).

It seems to be an array of sorts which stores the locations(not one, maybe) of different points(I don't really understand the zip part or how to get the points but it does).

But, the pt part(I assume from the print is the origin coordinates for the match on the big(original, haystack, whatever you call it) image), It will change from None to something.

**Solution**

which is adding an if statement to check `if pt != None:`

```
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
    if pt != None:
        #the things you want to do
        break #to allow the else function to work
else:
    #the things you want it to do when no template is detected
```

hope it solves your problem